# Returning a pointer to a structure malloc'ed in a function

Tags: c, function, pointers, scope, malloc

I'm using a function to malloc and initialise some memory for a hash function, like this:

```
int main (int argc, char * argv [])
{
  Bucket * hashTable;
  hashTable = createHashTable();
  ...
```

in 'main.c'

The function called in another file is this:

```
Bucket * createHashTable()
{
  Bucket * hashTable = malloc ( sizeof(Bucket) * HASHSIZE);
  int c=0;
  for (c=0;c<HASHSIZE;c++)
  {
    hashTable[c].key=NULL;
    hashTable[c].text=NULL;
    hashTable[c].next=NULL;
  }
  return hashTable;
}
```

My program compiles cleanly with '-pedantic -Wall', but segfaults. Using gdb, I get this:

```
Reading symbols from hash...done.
(gdb) break 11
Breakpoint 1 at 0x400990: file main.c, line 11.
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/user/Projects/random/hash 

Breakpoint 1, main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffdf78) at main.c:11
11    hashTable = createHashTable();
(gdb) print hashTable
$1 = (Bucket *) 0x400520 <_start>
(gdb) print * hashTable
$2 = {
key = 0x89485ed18949ed31 <error: Cannot access memory at address 0x89485ed18949ed31>, 
text = 0x495450f0e48348e2 <error: Cannot access memory at address
0x495450f0e48348e2>,    next = 0xc74800400a90c0c7}
(gdb)
```

The portion of the header with the struct "Bucket" definition:

```
typedef struct bucket{
  char * key;
  char * text;
  struct bucket * next;
} Bucket;
```

Is this a scope problem? When the function is finished, is it killing my malloc'ed memory or what?

Platform is 64bit Linux, and the address returned from the malloc() this time was 0x1665010 - I imagine if it had failed it would be NULL.

EDIT: The next function after this, in main.c, tries to add an entry to the table:

```
printf("Adding banana...\n");
addItem("Banana", "Bananas are yellow", &hashTable);
```

(yeah, yeah - bananas, I know) the function is:

```
void addItem(char * key, char * data, Bucket ** table)
{
  unsigned int hashkey;
  hashkey=hash(key);
  printf("%lu\n",strlen(key));
if (!table[hashkey]->text) /* SEGFAULTS HERE */
{
  table[hashkey]->key=key;
  table[hashkey]->text=data;
}
else
{
  Bucket * newListElement = malloc(sizeof(Bucket));
  newListElement->key=key;
  newListElement->text=data;
  newListElement->next = NULL;
  table[hashkey]->next = newListElement;
}
```

}

Comment: That seems valid. What platform are you on? Is `malloc` returning a valid address or failing (returning NULL)?

Comment: In order to help you verify this, you should provide a complete, minimal example. For example, which header files do you include? What is the definition of `Bucket`? etc...

Comment: Wait, are you sure it's crashing on that line? Your `break 11` command to GCC will break *before* the line is executed.

Comment: It crashes on the next line, I'll update the post...

Comment: I thought maybe the memory wasn't being initialised correctly so the if test highlighted above borked.

Comment: In the main c file, is there a prototype for `createHashTable()` visible?

Comment: To get good answers post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), otherwise we are just semi-randomly guessing common mistakes you might have made in the code you didn't show

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I'll do that in future

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
if (!table[hashkey]->text)
```

should be:

```
if ( !(*table)[hashkey]->text )
```

and similarly on following lines.  In this function, `table` is actually a pointer to the variable called `hashTable` in `main`.

Another way to fix this error would be to make the function take `Bucket *`, and not pass the address of `hashTable`.  There doesn't seem to be any need for the function to know the address of `hashTable` since it only puts things in the table.

Comment: That worked, that's great Thanks! Doesn't this mean that it's passed by value though and therefore updates to the table won't go past the function scope?

Comment: You don't update `table` anywhere in the function (unless there's more code you didn't post). Don't confuse `table` with the things being pointed to by `table`.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to reproduce this problem, but couldn't succeed.

So my only guess is that you might have omitted to present the right function signature to your main module, and there it is called as an `int createHashTable()`. This should lead to a warning and will make you lose the upper 32 bits of your resulting pointer IFF you have 64 bit pointers AND a 32 bit `int`.